# How to communicate between different programming languages?

Tags: javascript, python, api, communication-protocol

I have wrote an api for my python code like this:

```
def greet_in_python(name, greets="Hello"):
    ## in real life this implementation may be more complex and has other **python** dependencies
    ....
    return greets + " " + name
```

But only python developers can use my api.

What i want to do is the same thing but with a different language, like javascript, and without rewriting the whole code from python.
I thought there must be a way for javascript to communicate with this python api, execute it, and get the result so that javascript developers too can use my api.

```
greet_in_javascript(name, greets) {
    // talk to my python api
    // return the result easily
}
```

In a general sense how two languages can talk to each other?

Comment: There are many ways, but the most popular choice these days is using a REST API. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ for a Python based solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two very popular ways to do this, and probably a million others that I will neglect in my answer.

#### Pipes:

`import sys`

This is where your use `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` to read the inputs for your program with the help of your OS, then output the result. Both of these are file-like objects in Python so you are likely already familiar with how to use them. In js and node you have child processes and `exec` and so on which can do calls to your program e.g. `cat file.txt | python myscript.py`

#### APIs:

`import flask, django`

With this approach you can use frameworks like `flask` & `django` to define endpoints (e.g. `example.com/api/my/endpoint`) which map to your API in a way that makes sense for your business purpose. API design is too broad for me to delve into in this answer (but there are much better folks than I out in the internet who have written brilliantly about that topic.)

Edit:

#### Bonus: PubSub

I probably should also mention PubSub, which creates a message system that you can publish to and subscribe to, provided you are using a language that has a client for that PubSub system. For example here are all the clients for `redis` https://redis.io/clients and here is redis pubsub https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Comment: I was aware of the pipes method but i have always felt it is an unnatural way of doing it but since you pointed it out I wil try. For your second I don't want my api to depend on any framework at all. But can you point me to those people who wrote brilliantly a lot on the subject, any link?

Comment: I would start with https://swagger.io/solutions/api-design/ or https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask I personally found them helpful. If my response addressed your question you can mark it as helpful or answered